# How to flatten and reshape a json file into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, parent-child

I have a json file as following nested parent-child relation. A classic organization data of manager and its employees and so on.

An employee can manage one or more employees, and those employees can manage other employees. Nesting can go N-level deep.

**Input Data:**

```json
{
    "employee_id": "e1",
    "employee_name": "employee name 1",
    "join_date": "2011-01-01",
    " manages ": [
        {
            " employee_id ": " e11 ",
            " employee_name ": " employee name 11 ",
            " join_date ": " 2011 - 02 - 01 "
        },
        {
            " employee_id ": " e12 ",
            " employee_name ": " employee name 12 ",
            " join_date ": " 2011 - 02 - 02 ",
            " manages ": [
                {
                    " employee_id ": " e121 ",
                    " employee_name ": " employee name 121 ",
                    " join_date ": " 2011 - 02 - 21 "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to load them in a structured data frame. The Data frame should have the manager's id associated with the respective employee id.

Here, **Manager_id** is the "Employee ID" of the parent node.

**Expected Output:**
[image: Expected Output:]

Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is manager_id ?

Comment: Manager id is the "Employee ID" of the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

With the following json file which extends yours for the purpose of demonstration:

```py
{
    "employee_id": "e1",
    "employee_name": "employee name 1",
    "join_date": "2011-01-01",
    " manages ": [
        {
            " employee_id ": " e11 ",
            " employee_name ": " employee name 11 ",
            " join_date ": " 2011 - 02 - 01 "
        },
        {
            " employee_id ": " e12 ",
            " employee_name ": " employee name 12 ",
            " join_date ": " 2011 - 02 - 02 ",
            " manages ": [
                {
                    " employee_id ": " e121 ",
                    " employee_name ": " employee name 121 ",
                    " join_date ": " 2011 - 02 - 21 ",
                    " manages ": [
                        {
                            " employee_id ": " e1211 ",
                            " employee_name ": " employee name 1211 ",
                            " join_date ": " 2018 - 08 - 15 "
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            " employee_id ": " e13 ",
            " employee_name ": " employee name 13 ",
            " join_date ": " 2011 - 09 - 09 ",
            " manages ": [
                {
                    " employee_id ": " e131 ",
                    " employee_name ": " employee name 131 ",
                    " join_date ": " 2014 - 04 - 7 "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can define the following [recursive](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/) function:

```py
def func(data, new_data):
    """Recursive helper function.

    Args:
        data: input json data.
        new_data: empty target dict.

    Returns:
        reshaped data as dict.

    """
    data = {key.replace(" ", ""): value for key, value in data.items()}
    new_data["employee_id"].append(data["employee_id"])
    new_data["employee_name"].append(data["employee_name"])
    new_data["join_date"].append(data["join_date"])
    if data.get("manages", None):
        for item in data["manages"]:
            new_data["manager_id"].append(data["employee_id"])
            func(item, new_data)
    return new_data
```

Then:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("file.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Apply recursive func to json
df = pd.DataFrame(
    func(
        data,
        {"employee_id": [], "employee_name": [], "join_date": [], "manager_id": [None]},
    )
)

# Cleanup
df = df.apply(
    lambda x: x.str.replace(" - ", "-").str.rstrip(" ").str.lstrip(" ")
).fillna("")
```

And so:

```py
print(df)
# Output
0          e1     employee name 1  2011-01-01
1         e11    employee name 11  2011-02-01         e1
2         e12    employee name 12  2011-02-02         e1
3        e121   employee name 121  2011-02-21        e12
4       e1211  employee name 1211  2018-08-15       e121
5         e13    employee name 13  2011-09-09         e1
6        e131   employee name 131   2014-04-7        e13
```